# Rosenthal 2.6.1 - Proof that a probability measure is finitely additive.

Tags: probability-theory

In Rosenthal's "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory", I'm having trouble with exercise 2.6.1 b. The details of the problem are as follows.

Let $\Omega = \{0, 1\}^{\mathbb N}$ be our sample space, the set of binary sequences (indexed by $\mathbb N$). Each element of $\Omega$ represents a infinite number of tosses of a fair coin, with a $1$ being heads and a $0$ being tails. Now, let
$$
A_{a_1\cdots a_n} = \{(a_1,\cdots, a_n, r_{n+1},r_{n+2},\cdots)\ |\ r_i\in\{0,1\}\ i>n\}
$$
We define $P(A_{a_1\cdots a_n}) = \frac1{2^n}$ (naturally, as this is the probability of getting any fixed sequence of tosses of length $n$). Next, we define the semialgebra
$$
I = \{A_{a_1\cdots a_n}\ |\ n\in\mathbb{N},\ (a_1,\cdots, a_n)\in\{0,1\}^n\}
$$
We are tasked with showing that for any pairwise-disjoint finite family $D_i\in I$, that $P(\bigcup_i D_i) = \sum_i P(D_i)$, assuming that $\bigcup_i D_i\in I$.

I'm really struggling to formulate this properly. How should I be looking at the sets in $I$ in order to determine which families $D_i\in I$ have $\bigcup D_i\in I$? The criteria for when the family $D_i$ is pairwise-disjoint is very vague to me, and I have no clue what criteria give $\bigcup D_i\in I$, so I'm not sure how to even begin proving that $P$ is finitely additive.

How should I approach this?

Comment: What is your definition of semialgebra? It may be that the definition of $I$ is not quite right.

Comment: @angryavian According to Rosenthal a semialgebra $I$ on $\Omega$ is a collection of subsets of $\Omega$ which is closed under finite intersection, and for which the complements of elements in $I$ can be expressed as the finite disjoint union of sets in $I$. Also $\emptyset, \Omega\in I$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your definition of $I$ needs to also include $\varnothing$ and $\Omega$ in order to be a semi-algebra, and indeed the textbook includes them. But this is a minor typo.

---

The elements of $I$ are in direct correspondence with the possible finite sequences of coin flips via $A_{a_1, \ldots, a_n} \leftrightarrow (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ (for any $n$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in \{0, 1\}$).

An example of $\bigcup_i D_i$ that belongs to $I$ is
$$A_{1, 0, 0} \cup A_{1, 0, 1} \cup A_{1, 1, 0} \cup A_{1, 1, 1} = A_1 \in I.$$
I hope this shows you how $\bigcup_i D_i$ can belong to $I$: it must be the union of all sequences that have some common beginning sequence. (This is what the hint in the textbook is suggesting.)